# Make custom-triggered UIColorPickerViewController hug bottom of screen?

Tags: ios, swift, color-picker, presentviewcontroller

I am using custom control to trigger the presentation of a `UIColorPickerViewController`. It triggers the color picker, but not as expected.

I was using UIColorWell previously, which does present the picker  correctly (but it is an opaque implementation so I don't know how it does so).  I don't want to use UIColorWell, because the shape and appearance aren't right for where I'm invoking the picker from.

Everything works exactly as desired *except* I can't get the color picker to present at the *bottom* of the screen like `UIColorWell` would do it. Instead, whatever I've tried to present (or show),  `UIColorPickerController` appears near the *top* of the screen.

Note: Currently, to present the color picker controller, I'm using the latest iOS 15 trick with sheet controller / detents to try to anchor the picker to the bottom of the screen, but it's not working as expected (it's the technique is from the Apple Docs example, and as I've seen documented online).

What might be happening? What can I do to get the picker at the bottom of the screen, so that it doesn't obstruct my interface?

The Extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func findViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIViewController {
            return nextResponder
        } else if let nextResponder = self.next as? UIView {
            return nextResponder.findViewController()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
     }
}
```

Reproducible example (*almost*. It needs to be implemented/invoked from whatever VC [not shown here]):

This is custom control that that creates a rectangular color picker view (I'm using it to replace UIColorWell). It attempts to locate the VC which contains the view of which this custom control is a subview.

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class RectangularColorWell : UIControl {

    var colorPickerController = UIColorPickerViewController()

    var selectedColor : UIColor = UIColor.clear

    var lineWidth : CGFloat = 4.0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
      
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        colorPickerController.supportsAlpha = false
        colorPickerController.delegate = self
        selectedColor = backgroundColor ?? UIColor.clear
        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CustomToggleControl.controlTapped(_:)))
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        ctx.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
        ctx.setFillColor(backgroundColor!.cgColor)
        ctx.fill(rect)
        drawGradientBorder(rect, context: ctx)
    }
    
    
    func drawGradientBorder(_ rect: CGRect, context: CGContext) {
        context.saveGState()
        context.setLineWidth(lineWidth)
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        context.addPath(path.cgPath)
        context.replacePathWithStrokedPath()
        context.clip()
        
        let rainbowColors : [UIColor] = [ .red, .orange, .yellow, .green, .blue, .purple ]
        let colorDistribution : [CGFloat] =  [  0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0 ]
        let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), colors: rainbowColors.map { $0.cgColor } as CFArray, locations: colorDistribution)!
        context.drawLinearGradient(gradient, start: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), end: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height), options: [])
        context.restoreGState()
    }

    
    @objc func controlTapped(_ gestureRecognizer :UIGestureRecognizer) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.5
        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.alpha = 1.0
            }, completion: { (finished: Bool) -> Void in
            })
        })

        setNeedsDisplay()
        let vc = self.findViewController()
        if let sheet = vc?.sheetPresentationController {
             sheet.detents = [.medium()]
             sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .medium
             sheet.prefersScrollingExpandsWhenScrolledToEdge = false
             sheet.prefersEdgeAttachedInCompactHeight = true
             sheet.widthFollowsPreferredContentSizeWhenEdgeAttached = true
            
        }
        vc?.present(colorPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        sendActions(for: .touchDown)
    }
}

extension RectangularColorWell : UIColorPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller : UIColorPickerViewController) {
        self.selectedColor = controller.selectedColor
    }
    
    func colorPickerViewController(_ controller : UIColorPickerViewController, didSelect color: UIColor, continuously: Bool) {
        self.backgroundColor = color
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don’t think the color picker would respect sheet configuration. Unlike other sheets, it’s as tall as it needs to be - the interface doesn’t scroll and so couldn’t be shorter in height. The color picker came to iOS before the existence of detents. But maybe you can add screenshots to your question showing what it looks like vs what the color well looked like.

Comment: @JordanH okay let me see what I can do for pics. Hang tight. Thanks for the point about the sheet not being respected. The picker takes up between 1/2 and 3/4 of the iPhone 13 Pro Max screen, the difference is that when triggered by UIColorWell it's anchored to the bottom of the screen and when I present it floats near the top covering the custom colorwell and other controlls.

Comment: @JordanH okay, I uploaded the before custom-colorwell-press and after. The picker slides up from the bottom.

Comment: Can you show what the color picker looked like when it was presented from UIColorWell, to show what you’re expecting it to look like?

Comment: @JordanH That would be a hassle since I've already axed the code, just imagine the picker slid down so that the black rounded rect square at the bottom of the picker (left of the circular swatches)  is near the bottom of the screen and the custom color well and controlls are showing above the title of the picker.

Comment: That’s what it should look like if you present the color picker without changing any of the sheet presentation controller’s properties - the color picker sheet is only as tall as its contents. It seems something you’re setting is turning it into a full height sheet.

Answer (score 0):

@JordanH's final comment caused me to read up on the show/present methods on UIViewController docs. The default presentation style was what I'd been using (e.g. I hadn't set any of the presentation options on the color picker's view controller when I filed the question.

Surprisingly after reading that I could control the style, setting the picker's `modalPresentationStyle` property to '.pageSheet' which is the one that looks like it would work, to do a partial covering,  did not work!.

The solution turned out to be adding `colorPickerController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover` before calling `present()`in the custom RectangularColorWellView). It now behaves as if it was presented from a UIColorWell control view.